# unexpected EOF while looking for matching error

Tags: bash, shell

I am running below script and getting

> error script.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>   script.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file.

Though I tried to run line 9 manually n it runs without error.

```
alias gxt="awk -F "_" '{print \$1}' test | uniq"
count = $(cat test | awk -F "_" '{print $1} | uniq | wc -l)

for i in {1..count};
        do
        User=$(gxt | head -n $i)
        recharge=$(grep -E "$User.recharge" test| awk -F "_" '{print $3}' | xargs ) 
        total1=( $((${recharge// /+})))   
        sales=$(grep -E "$User.sale" test| awk -F "_" '{print $3}' | xargs ) 
        total2=( $((${sales// /+})))
        balance=`expr $total1 - $total2`
        echo $User.balance.$balance >> result
        done
```

Comment: Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix syntax issues. You have an un-terminated single quote after line containing the alias and extra spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=$(cat test | awk -F "_" '{print $1}` | uniq | wc -l)
```

1. missing `'` at the end of {print $1}
2. Inadvertently added spaces around `=`

Answer (score 0):

Other than the issues already reported and those exposed by shellcheck, there is another issue:

```
for i in {1..count};
```

'count' cannot be a variable. It can only be a constant.
Change it to

```
for ((i = 1; i <= count; i++)); do whatever ; done
```